# Searching pre-1998 Indonesia Kabupaten (Level 2) shapefile

Tags: shapefile, data, indonesia

I am trying to find some "old" (pre-1998) Indonesia boundary shapefiles at the Kabupaten and province levels.

It is important that they are pre-1998, or at least dating before the peak of the secession of the regencies. Does anybody know where I can find them?

Comment: What if you give a try on the [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) platform?

Answer (score 1):

http://tanahair.indonesia.go.id/portal-web

This might help you, is Indonesian language but still very comprehensive data about boundaries in kabupaten/kota and province in Indonesia.